# How to handle not existing columns when binding data with entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, api, .net-core

I'm implementing a REST API in c# .net core 2.2 using entity framework to communicate with a database. The pronblem is, I'm using stored procedure from sql server and switch the case, it will return more or less columns.
So I'm calling this stored procedure using DbQuery from EF, and I've created an object to do the data binding with the result of the stored procedure.

My problem is, when doing the data binding, entity framework expects the stored procedure to return all the properties defined, but there is one who's missing.

```
public class ModelBinding {
  public string column1
  public string column2
}
```

**First Example:**
Result stored procedure :
*column1 = 4,
column2 = 3*

**Second Example:**
Result stored procedure :
*column1 = 2*

In the second example, the stored procedure return only 1 property (column1) but entity framework needs to have the 2 of them.

Do you have any idea of how to put the second column optional or how to handle this situation ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you update your procedure to always return all columns? If there is no value, just return NULLs.

Comment: That was one of the solution i throught of, however I don't manage the procedure, it's an other one job and he has a lot of work, so I try to find an other way to do this. but I think I would not have the choice. Thanks for your answer !